# Coding for share buttons on blog

Tags: button, hyperlink, share

I used a premade blogger template for my blog. 
I figured out how to code everything the way I like, but for the life of me I can't figure out how to correctly code the buttons so they go to the right destinations. I'd appreciate any help!!

```
<b:includable id='shareButtons' var='post'>
   <a class='goog-inline-block share-button sb-email' expr:href='data:post.sharePostUrl      + &quot;&amp;target=email&quot;' expr:title='data:top.emailThisMsg' target='_blank'>
     <span class='share-button-link-text'><data:top.emailThisMsg/></span>[/url]
   <a class='goog-inline-block share-button sb-blog' expr:href='data:post.sharePostUrl     + &quot;&amp;target=blog&quot;' expr:onclick='&quot;window.open(this.href,     \&quot;_blank\&quot;, \&quot;height=270,width=475\&quot;); return false;&quot;'     expr:title='data:top.blogThisMsg' target='_blank'>
    <span class='share-button-link-text'><data:top.blogThisMsg/></span>[/url]
  <a class='goog-inline-block share-button sb-twitter'     expr:href='data:post.sharePostUrl + &quot;&amp;target=twitter&quot;'     expr:title='data:top.shareToTwitterMsg' target='_blank'>
    <span class='share-button-link-text'><data:top.shareToTwitterMsg/></span>[/url]
  <a class='goog-inline-block share-button sb-facebook'      expr:href='data:post.sharePostUrl + &quot;&amp;target=facebook&quot;'     expr:onclick='&quot;window.open(this.href, \&quot;_blank\&quot;,     \&quot;height=430,width=640\&quot;); return false;&quot;'     expr:title='data:top.shareToFacebookMsg' target='_blank'>
    <span class='share-button-link-text'><data:top.shareToFacebookMsg/></span>[/url]
  <a class='goog-inline-block share-button sb-buzz' expr:href='data:post.sharePostUrl +     &quot;&amp;target=buzz&quot;' expr:onclick='&quot;window.open(this.href,     \&quot;_blank\&quot;, \&quot;height=415,width=690\&quot;); return false;&quot;'     expr:title='data:top.shareToBuzzMsg' target='_blank'>
    <span class='share-button-link-text'><data:top.shareToBuzzMsg/></span>[/url]
  <b:if cond='data:top.showDummy'>
    <div class='goog-inline-block dummy-container'><data:post.dummyTag/></div>
  </b:if>
</b:includable>
```